# ¿Como obtener las cordenadas de un punto en google-maps?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-geocoding-api

El usuario puede desplazarse en el mapa, el marcador estatico inmedio de la pantalla, indica el punto que se quiere obtener las cordenadas, al presionar el boton, me debe obtener las cordenadas del punto seleccionado.

[image: referencia]

Comment: Puedes proporcionar como lo tienes hasta ahora ? codigo.

Comment: tengo realizados los widgets, el mapa se ve en la pantalla, pero no entiendo como obtener las cordenadas del mapa, con referencia a la parte inferior(la punta) del marcador

Comment: Como te han indicado, pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has hecho hasta el momento. Describe además el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo: "no entiendo cómo" no es argumento suficiente. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 2):

La pregunta no se entiende. Tienes que tener en cuenta que no estamos en tu mente, por tanto, si no expresas correctamente qué y cómo quieres hacerlo, es imposible ayudarte.

Además, deberías proveer el código de lo que llevas intentando o ser más específico en qué parte no consigues hacer. Literalmente estás pidiendo que adivinemos qué problema tienes y que te lo resolvamos.

Por lo poco que he conseguido entender, puedes tener uno de estos dos problemas:

1. Necesitas que el usuario haga click en el mapa y obtener las coordenadas de dónde ha hecho click.

Para este problema, te planteo la siguiente solución:

```dart
GoogleMap(
  // all the other arguments
  onTap: (latLng) {
    print('${latLng.latitude}, ${latLng.longitude}');
  }
);
```

Respuesta original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044839/how-to-get-lat-long-on-map-tap-in-flutter

El propio widget de Google Maps para flutter tiene la propiedad onTap, la cual detecta la pulsación del usuario en el mapa y devuelve la localización (latitud y longitud) de donde se ha hecho click.

2. Tienes diferentes marcadores en el mapa y quieres controlar a qué marcador se ha hecho click.

Si esta es la pregunta, primero te recomendaría leerte la doc de Google Map y ver qué propiedades tienen las clases que vienen con el SDK.

Los markers tienen una propiedad llamada `onTap`, que te permite llamar a un `callback` cuando el usuario selecciona alguno. En el `onTap` puedes enviar una función que busque por el id del marker en la lista de markers que debes tener. El Marker ya tiene la longitud y la latitud en sus propiedades, podrías acceder a ellas y hacer lo que quieras.

Puedes revisar el siguiente ejemplo para hacerte una idea:
https://gist.github.com/sh0umik/05ab4cad0d4604056e715551d67cb063

Si tu duda es otra diferente, te recomendaría que la aclares.

Si alguna de las respuestas resuelve la duda, te agradecería que la marcaras como la respuesta correcta.